# Java Swing - Jlabel ActionListener won't print out selected Checkbox

Tags: java, swing, checkbox, actionlistener, jlist

I have a JList which allows you to select which options to "cancel". Once the cancel button is clicked, a JLabel prints out which options have been cancelled. However, when I try to test the code, and I select the options and click "cancel", the JLabel prints nothing. So I'm assuming the ActionListener for the cancel button does not work. I have included the relevant code below:

```
public class WarehouseInterface extends JFrame{
private JFrame frame;

public WarehouseInterface(){

    frame = new JFrame("Warehouse Interface");


    DefaultListModel demoList = new DefaultListModel();
    HashMap<String, Job> jobHashMap = SharedInformation.jobs;

    int i = 0;
    ArrayList<String> jobIDs = new ArrayList<>();
    Iterator it = jobHashMap.entrySet().iterator();

    while (it.hasNext() && i < 10) {
        Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
        Job job = (Job) pair.getValue();    
        String jobID = job.getID();
        demoList.add(i, jobID);
        jobIDs.add(jobID);
        i++;
    }

    JList list = new JList(demoList);
    list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
    list.setCellRenderer(new CheckList());

    JButton cancel = new JButton("Cancel");
    cancel.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 14));

    JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
    panel2.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,0));
    panel2.add(list);
    panel2.add(cancel);

    JPanel panel3 = new JPanel();
    panel3.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,0));
    panel3.add(label3);

    ActionListener cancelListener = new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

            for(int index : list.getSelectedIndices()) {
                String jobID = (String) demoList.get(index);
                JLabel cancelledJobLabel = new JLabel(jobID);
                cancelledJobLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 20));
                cancelledJobLabel.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 18));
                cancelledJobLabel.setOpaque(true);
                panel3.add(cancelledJobLabel);
                //ERROR HERE :(
            }

        }
    };
    cancel.addActionListener(cancelListener);

    frame.add(panel2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.add(panel3, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);     


}
    class CheckList extends JLabel implements ListCellRenderer {

        @Override
        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, 
                        int index, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus) {

            setComponentOrientation(list.getComponentOrientation());

            if (isSelected) {
                 setBackground(Color.RED);
                 setForeground(Color.WHITE);

             // unselected, and not the DnD drop location
             } else {
                 setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                 setForeground(Color.BLACK);
             };

            setOpaque(true);
            setEnabled(list.isEnabled());
            setFont(list.getFont());
            setText(value.toString());
            return this;
        }


    }
```

Comment: `So I'm assuming the ActionListener for the cancel button does not work.` - Don't assume. Test your theory. Add some System.out.println(...) statements to the ActionLIstener to see if they ever get executed.

Comment: @camickr Added some prints and they appeared so I guess that's not the issue. The jobID string isn't an empty string either since the ActionListener prints those out too. So the only issue it can be is that the JLabel cancelledJobLabel doesn't want to show it.

Comment: @Berger sorry that's just a copy and paste error. I have editted the code above to include it.

Answer (score 3):

```
panel3.add(cancelledJobLabel);
```

When you add/remove components to a visible GUI the basic code is:

```
panel.add(...);
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
```

The `revalidate()` invokes the layout manager. Otherwise the component has a size of (0, 0) so there is nothing to paint.

Comment: This worked! I wasn't aware of the revalidate or repaint method. But will use them in future code. Thank you again :)

Comment: @assassinweed2, glad the suggestion helped. Don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the checkmark so people know the problem has been solved.